# My code doesn't iterate through a list in a file

Tags: python, list, python-requests

So I have a list of path traversal payloads in DirTraversal.txt, but for some weird reason when sending the requests it stops at the first line and it just hangs. It doesn't give me any errors or anything, it just stops sending the request after the first line.

I tried removing the concurrent.future part of the code and just iterate through a normal for loop, but I get the same result.

```
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import concurrent.futures
import requests
import os
import sys


filepath = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())

payload = "".join((filepath, "/wordlists/DirTraversal.txt"))
with open(f"{payload}", "r") as f:
    dirtraversal = (x.strip() for x in f.readlines())


def get_request(url: str):
    ua = UserAgent()
    header = {'User-Agent':str(ua.chrome)}
    s = requests.Session()
    r = s.get(f"{url}", headers=header)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        if b"root:x:" in r.content:
            print(f"{Fore.GREEN} VULNERABLE {Fore.CYAN} - {Fore.WHITE} {url}")
        else:
            print(f"{Fore.RED} NOT VULNERABLE {Fore.CYAN} - {Fore.WHITE} {url}")  
    else:
        print("Error") 


def PathTraversal(dirtraversal):
    target = input("Site: ")
    check = "".join((target, dirtraversal))
    get_request(check)

if __name__== "__main__":
    try:
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
            executor.map(PathTraversal, dirtraversal)
    except KeyboardInterrupt as err:
        sys.exit(0)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: do you know what `input` does?

Comment: Are you actually typing in a site? The code will hang until you do, but that has nothing to do with your file being read. Please create a [mcve]

Comment: if you type anything in the input the script will crash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `dirtraversal` variable is a list of urls. when you feed your `map` with it, it will execute multiple times `PathTraversal` with *one* of the links

`input` will wait for you to input anything, and will hang until you hit `enter`. `join` will add whatever you typed at the start of the url, and `requests` won't like that. maybe you just wanted to `print`

```
def PathTraversal(url):
    print(f"Site: {url}")
    get_request(url)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should just remove `input` from code. `input` waits for you to enter a string on the terminal
If your DirTraversal.txt file contains the urls, then you can simply remove `input` and do a `get_request(url)` instead.